# Need help on Fourier Series.

Tags: fourier-series

I am trying to find the Fourier Series of $u=x^2(x-\pi)^2$. Given
$$u_x(0)=u_x(\pi)=0$$
Using the even extension I got
$$a_0=\frac{2}{\pi}\int_0^\pi x^2(x-\pi)^2 dx $$
$$\Rightarrow a_0=\frac{\pi^4}{15}$$
$$a_n=\frac{2}{\pi}\int_0^\pi [x^2(x-\pi)^2](\cos(nx))dx$$
$$\Rightarrow a_n=-\frac{24(\cos(\pi n)+1)}{n^4} $$
$$\Rightarrow u=\frac{\pi^4}{30}-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{24(\cos(\pi n)+1)}{n^4}\cos (nx)$$

I tried to plot it but it was not quite the same as $u=x^2(x-\pi)^2$. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The even extension of $f$ to $[-\pi,\pi]$ gives $f(x)=x^{2}(\pi+x)^{2}$ for $x <0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\on}[1]{\operatorname{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
Define
$\ds{\bbox[5px,#ffd]{\on{f}\pars{x} =
\left\{\begin{array}{lcl}
\ds{\on{f}\pars{-x}} & \mbox{if} & \ds{x < 0}
\\[1mm]
\ds{x^{2}\pars{x - \pi}^{2}} & \mbox{if} & \ds{0 \leq x \leq \pi}
\\[1mm]
\ds{\on{f}\pars{x - \pi}} & \mbox{if} & \ds{x > \pi}
\end{array}\right.}}$

which is an *even* and *periodic* function
of *period* $\ds{\pi}$ which looks like the following picture:

[image]

---

Lets $\ds{\on{f}\pars{x} = a_{0} +
\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}a_{n}\cos\pars{2nx}}$
$$
\mbox{with}\quad
\left\{\begin{array}{lcl}
\ds{\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\cos\pars{2mx}\cos\pars{2mx}
\,\dd x} & \ds{=} & \ds{{\pi \over 2}\,\delta_{mn}}
\\[2mm]
\ds{\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\cos\pars{2nx}\,\dd x} & \ds{=} &  \ds{\pi\,\delta_{n0}}
\end{array}\right.
$$

- $\ds{\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\on{f}\pars{x}\,\dd x =
  {\pi^{5} \over 30} \implies \bbx{a_{0} =
  {\pi^{4} \over 30}}}$.
- $\ds{\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\on{f}\pars{x}\cos\pars{2nx}\,\dd x =
  -{3\pi \over 2}\,{1 \over n^{4}} \implies \bbx{a_{n} =
  -{3 \over n^{4}}}}$.

---

\begin{align}
\on{f}\pars{x} & =
{\pi^{4} \over 30} -
3\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{\cos\pars{2nx} \over n^{4}} =
\bbx{6\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}
{\sin^{2}\pars{nx} \over n^{4}}}
\label{1}\tag{1}
\\ &
\end{align}
because
$\ds{\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{1 \over n^{4}} = {\pi^{4} \over 90}}$.

In plotting the above series ( see (\ref{1}) ), you'll get the above picture *again*.